Multidimensional Fourier Transform derived from the one dimensional case
Many authors (Rudin, Axler,...) study the Fourier Transform primarily in $\mathbb{R}$, which raises the question: Is this because of pedagogical reasons or because the multidimensional case can be derived from the one dimensional results? In particular, can the multidimensional Plancharel theorem be proven using the one dimensional one? Inversion formula? I'd be thankful for a bit of thoughts.

For functions on $\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m$, let $F,F_n,F_m$ respectively be the full Fourier transform, the Fourier transform with respect to the first set of variables, the Fourier transform with respect to the second set of variables. Then, it follows (Fubini) that $F=F_n\circ F_m=F_m\circ F_n$ (when acting on a suitable class of functions of course). So yes, once you have the Fourier transform on $\Bbb{R}$, you can repeat it $n$ times to get it on $\Bbb{R}^n$.
But I don’t really see how this simplifies things (especially since Rudin in his RCA has already introduced all the measure-theoretic background).
